# Ruby blocks within an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, block

I need an array of blocks, where each block can take an argument:

```
array = [
  block do |x| puts x end,
  block do |x| puts x.to_s+" - " end
]
```

and make a request in the form of:

```
array[0] << 34
```

I had an idea to convert large numbers into words. I was wondering about the limits of blocks. There may be another way of doing it, but I am curious if this is possible.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand a word of what you are willing to do concretly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lambdas:

```
array = [ lambda { |x| puts x }, lambda { |x| puts "#{x} - " } ]

array[0].call(34) # prints 34
```

---

If you need to use the `<<` operator to invoke the [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html), then you can create a class and overload it:

```
class Foo
    def initialize( &proc )
        @proc = proc
    end
    def <<( input )
        @proc.call( input )
    end
end

array = [
    Foo.new { |x| puts x },
    Foo.new { |x| puts "#{x} - " } ]

array[0] << 34 # prints 34
```

Comment: I start to like ruby :) 
Thank you that  was simpler then i thought !

Comment: use of << was a wild guess .... :) 
dam i did not think of this , even though i  knew about  overriding functions :)

Answer (score 7):

While you're getting answers that tell you what is possible with Ruby procs and lambdas, I think it's important to understand that blocks are *not* objects in Ruby and cannot be included in arrays or otherwise manipulated as Ruby objects. They only come into existence in conjunction with a method call.

I'd like to be able to point you to some official/complete documentation on the subject of blocks, procs and lambdas, but while there's a lot of stuff out there, most of it has some subtle but important flaws imho. However, if you google for Ruby blocks, procs and lambdas, you'll get something that is at least 90% accurate.

Comment: +1 Good point. As a result of your answer, I changed all instances of "block" in my answer to "proc", since that is technically what they are.

Answer (score 3):

To run it through a specific lambda:

```
a = [
  ->(x) { puts x },
  ->(x) { puts "#{x} - " }
]

a[0].(34) # => prints 34
```

To run it through every block:

```
a.map { |b| b.(3) }
```

Comment: This looks less initiative for me but i will test is as well 
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Well i actually want to run through items manually as i need to  put some additional logic before, but it looks like it can come handy at some point :)

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternate syntax :)